# Geocoding Web service api returns OVER_QUERY_LIMIT after 8 queries

Tags: google-maps, google-geocoding-api

I have been doing geocoding to prefetch groups of addresses.

Since the last week, I have been getting the OVER_QUERY_LIMIT result returned after only handling 8 addresses.

So, I am still well within the 2500 requests per day and I give a 2 second pause between each request.

Has there been a change in procedure ?

I have checked the API documentation to verify that it hasn't changed since last year.
My code is exactly the same as before, so I am wondering what has changed.

Answer (score 0):

Likely you are sharing your server with another user that is counting in your quota, since the quota is by IP address.  Does your code operate from it's own IP address or are you sharing the server with other users?